# how to keep value in a listbox in PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, jquery

I got a listbox in my php page that generate from another listbox, the code is as follows

```
<?php $myArray1 = $_POST['countryRF'];?>
                    <select name='countryRF[]' id='countryRF' size='10' multiple style='width:180px' class='selfont'>
                    <?php
                    foreach($myArray1 as $value){ // Loop through each element
                          print "<option value=\"".$value."\">".$value."</option>";
                    }
                    ?>
                    </option></select>
```

While refreshing the form listbox get empty, how can I keep added values even after form reload ?

**Is it possible to keep the mysql result table stable even after form reloading by session ? If so please give me a help ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i see you get the 'countryRF' from post.

you can store it in a cookie/session, of store it on the server.

use

```
if (isset($_POST['countryRF'])) {
    $_COOKIE['countryRF'] = $_POST['countryRF'];
}
$myArray = $_COOKIE['countryRF'];
```

same goes with session

Comment: <code><?php
                    if (isset($_POST['countryRF'])) {
         $_COOKIE['countryRF'] = $_POST['countryRF'];
     }
                    $myArray1 = $_COOKIE['countryRF'];
                    ?>
                    <select name='countryRF[]' id='countryRF' size='10' multiple style='width:180px' class='selfont'>
                    <?php
     foreach($myArray1 as $value){ // Loop through each element
        print "<option value=\"".$value."\">".$value."</option>";
     }
     ?>
     </option></select><code>
still listbox empty ?

Comment: you have an extra </option> before the </select> btw

Answer (score 1):

save them into [Sessions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php)